# Reading vector information instead when trying to read filename to create custom dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Using python v `3.7.3`, pytorch v `0.4.1`, windows 10, running code on Jupyter

I am pretty new to programming and deep learning, and creating a new dataset by combining 2 existing datasets.  I am trying to read the filenames of the images but instead it is returning the vector information.  Here is a snippet of the output (`imgname` is the path, `names` should just be the filename eg `vinegar_41`):

```
imgname: C:\Users\User\Documents\Dataset\train\vinegar\vinegar_41.png

 names:  [[[128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]
  ...
  [128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]]

 [[128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]
  ...
  [128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]
  [128 128 128]]
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
__all__ = ['MyDataset']

class MyDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, root, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        root = train_set
        print(root)
        root_list = os.listdir(root)
        print(root_list)
        for f in root_list:
            print('checkpoint')
            imgs = []
            for img in os.listdir(f):
                #print('\n image: ', img)
                imgname = (root + '\\' + f + '\\' + img)
                print('\n imgname:', imgname)
                open(imgname, 'r')
                if img.endswith('.png'):
                    names = cv2.imread(imgname)
                    imgs.append(names)
                    #print('\n imgs: ', imgs)
                    print('\n names: ', names)

                #Image.close()
        self.imgs = imgs
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        fn, label = self.imgs[index]
        img = PIL.Image.open(fn).convert('RGB')
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            label = self.transform(label)
        return img, label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.imgs)
```

I'm in over my head, but my project is due in a couple days, so any advice on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cv2.imread(imgname)` reads the content of the file `imgname`. The filename itself should already be contained in `imgname`

Comment: Do you mean in `img`?  Any advice on how to change the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from skimage import io


class MyDataset(Dataset):
    """My dataset."""

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None,
                 target_transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with labels.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
            target_transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to 
                be applied on a label.
        """
        self.label = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.label)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.label.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = io.imread(img_name)
        sample = image
        lab = self.label.iloc[idx, 1]

        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            lab = self.target_transform(lab)

        return sample, lab
```

The csv file should look like:

```
fname,label
image1.png,1
image2.png,0
image3.png,1
...
imagen.png,0
```

Comment: Is a csv file required?  I was hoping to just get the names from the file itself.  But, if that is not possible, then I can create a csv file.

Comment: @Sanglang there needs to be a way to identify the labels. So either that is a csv or if you want it in a directory there needs to be subdirectories that correspond to the different labels. So within the root_dir there are sub_dirs for each label containing the images corresponding to that label

Comment: how I have it right now is the root_dir would be "train", and the sub_dirs would be the different classes, e.g., "vinegar", and in vinegar contains all the vinegar images, etc.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Sanglang yes exactly. Or you can make the csv file as I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to retrieve image info without making a csv file

```
    def __init__(self, root, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        class_list = os.listdir(root)
        class_list.sort()
        #print(class_list)


        label_mapping = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(class_list)}

        imgs = []

        for f in class_list:
            for img in os.listdir(f):
                img = os.path.join(root, f, img)
                label = label_mapping[f]
                imgs.append((img, label))
        self.imgs = imgs
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform
```